# Stack buffer overrun (Windows, C++) : how can I detect the culprit?

Tags: windows, visual-c++, stack, buffer, overrun

Are there any tools/libraries on Windows that can help me tarck down the culprit? This is a fairly large codebase, with multiple threads.

I code for Linux mostly; Windows is unfamiliar territory. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For stack buffers, compile with /GS, see [Compiler Security Checks In Depth](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa290051)
For heap buffer, you can try the heap gflag, see [GFlags and PageHeap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc265936.aspx), but need to be careful as all allocations, big or small, will get their own page.